# Date Field, User Locale and Visual Force Problem

Tags: visualforce, date, user, locale

I have a scenario, where i am implementing a VF page which is basically a Registration Page with DOB validating if the user is above 18. It also has style class and javascript attached to validation. Date format is set to MM/DD/YYYY

```
  $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
```

But, since i am handling the same page for diff location users, if a user locale changes the page doesn't redirect to next page. I tried to resolve this issue by changing it to DD/MM/YYYY then for specific users with that format page gets redirected.

```
If (profileName.lastIndexOf("(Singapore)") > -1)
{
var dateArr = $(".datetimepicker").val().split("/");
$(".datetimepicker").val(dateArr[1]+"/"+dateArr[0]+"/"+dateArr[2]);
}
```

So, is it the same way we have to handle for all differing locales. And after this fix Back button doesn't work when i pick a date in the form.